# np.concatenate doesn't allow sequential concatenation

Tags: python, numpy

I have been trying to concatenate two 1D arrays using np.concatenate but it doesn't work as expected. Can someone please let me know where I'm making a mistake?

My code is as follows:

```
x = np.array([1.13793103, 0.24137931, 0.48275862, 1.24137931, 1.00000000, 1.89655172])
y = np.array([0.03666667, 0.00888889, 0.01555556, 0.04      , 0.03222222, 0.06111111])

z = np.concatenate((x,y), axis=0)

print(z)
array([1.13793103, 0.24137931, 0.48275862, ... 0.04, 0.03222222, 0.06111111])

print(f'{type(x)} {type(y)} {type(z)}')
<class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'> <class 'numpy.ndarray'>

print(f'{x.shape} {y.shape} {z.shape}')
(6,) (6,) (12,)
```

So, instead of adding y as a new array, it's joining the two arrays which isn't my intention. I am looking for something as follows:

```
array([1.13793103, 0.24137931, 0.48275862, 1.24137931, 1.00000000, 1.89655172],
      [0.03666667, 0.00888889, 0.01555556, 0.04      , 0.03222222, 0.06111111])
```

Comment: instead of `np.concatenate`, you can do `np.vstack`

Comment: That helps! Great. Can you also tell me where am I going wrong here?

Comment: `print(z)` doesn't print what you show in your question. I have no idea where you got that from, but `np.concatenate` does exactly what you expect it to do.

Comment: `x` and `y` are 1d. `concatenate` joins them on that 1 axis, resulting in a longer 1d array, You want a 2d array.  `z = np.array([x, y])` should work.

Comment: @a_guest, sorry about that! that was a huge 1D array. I made it simple to ask the question but missed out some ..... in the process.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `np.concatenate` to concatenate along some axis if that dimension exists in the arrays that you want to concatenate:

```
x = np.array([1,2,3])
y = np.array([4,5,6])
```

here, x and y have shape (3,) so only one axis.
This means you can only concatenate along that axis (i.e. axis=0):

```
z = np.concatenate((x,y))
z.shape
out : (6,)
```

concatenating along axis=1 will throw an error:

```
z = np.concatenate((x,y), axis=1)
AxisError: axis 1 is out of bounds for array of dimension 1
```

You can make np.concatenate work, if you reshape x and y:

```
x, y = x.reshape(-1,1), y.reshape(-1,1)
```

Now both have shape (3,1) and can be concatenated along axis 1:

```
z = np.concatenate((x.reshape(-1,1),y.reshape(-1,1)),axis=1)
z.shape
(6,2)
```

alternatively, you can reshape to (1,3) and concatenate along axis 0:

```
z = np.concatenate((x.reshape(1,-1),y.reshape(1,-1)),axis=0)
z.shape
(2,6)
```

or you use `np.vstack`, which does not require the reshaping.